# How to set value on the `path` attribute of a spring form `select` element?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a java web project based on springmvc.

On one page, a html source snippet is as below:

```
<form:select id="goodSelectId" path="goodId" items="${goodsList}"
      itemLabel="name" itemValue="goodCode">
      <form:option value="">select the product</form:option>
</form:select>


<form:checkbox path="flag" id="flag" value="1"
      onchange="change(this, 'goodSelectId')"/>
```

related jquery function ：

```
    function change(self, targetId) {
        if ($(self).is(':checked')) {
            $("#" + targetId).val("");
            $("#" + targetId).attr("disabled", true);      
        }
        else {
            $("#" + targetId).attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }
```

When I tick the checkbox, I want to make the select element value null, and then disable the select element.

"disable" is Ok, but **the value "" can't be set to  `path` of select:form.**

That is:

1) if I USE select drop-down to choose a option, the value can be passed to `path`

2) but if I set the value through the javascript function above, the value can't be passed to `path`

my question is: how can I pass the value set inside the javascript function to `path`?

Comment: You are getting empty on alert because its missing `$` in the alert

Comment: @MilanChheda ah, typo, it has $, but I got empty on alert.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your options values are `1` or `2`.
Try this line:

```
  $("#" + targetId).val(1);
```

Your modified code:

```js
function change(self, targetId) {
  if ($(self).is(':checked')) {
    $("#" + targetId).val(1);
    $("#" + targetId).attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#" + targetId).attr("disabled", false);
  }

  $("#show").html($("#" + targetId).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="">请选择</option>
  <option value="1">选项一</option>
  <option value="2">选项二</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="flag" value="1" onchange="change(this, 'test')" />

<p id="show">xx</p>
```

Comment: you are right, I get it, but still another problem is: the value can't be saved to `path` of the select:form element, how to deal with this?

Comment: seems like a different question to be honest. you should close this one (if the answer helped to this specific question) and open a new one with the relevant details and code snippets.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6373j3k6/7/ I'm now confused, coz this from the link you can see that the `p` element can't display the value, what is wrong?

Comment: you have no `p` element in this fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I used `$("#" + targetId + ' option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');` and seems thats what you are looking for, check the code below:

```js
function change(self, targetId) {
  if ($(self).is(':checked')) {
    $("#" + targetId + ' option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $("#" + targetId).attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $("#" + targetId).attr("disabled", false);
  }

  $("#show").html($("#" + targetId).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="">请选择</option>
  <option value="1">选项一</option>
  <option value="2">选项二</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="flag" value="1" onchange="change(this, 'test')" />

<p id="show">xx</p>
```

Comment: you are right, I get it, but still another problem is: the value can't be saved to `path` of the select:form element, how to deal with this?

Comment: You mean the `path` attribute of the select should have selected value??

Comment: yes, but I'm now confused, from the link  https://jsfiddle.net/6373j3k6/7/ you can see that the `p` element can't display the value, what is wrong?

Comment: There is no `p` element in that link. You have missed adding `<p id="show">xx</p>` to your HTML.